Electron : Can I read Personal user certificate in Windows certificate Store?
I'm begin to electron.
I have a esignature website.
Electronic signing can be done with signings keys (EIDAS) and self-signed certificate who are stored in the personal store of the local user in Windows.
But with my eletron app (which is a simple web page call), I cannot access/select these certificates. I don't see them. (However I can see EIDAS physical keys.)
Chrome/Chromium succeeded to read the personal store Windows without manipulations, I thought it would be the same for Electron.
Is there a particular function or permissions to call in my app?
PS : I cannot call a pfx or crt file directly, I do read user store certificate)
Thanks,
Regards
(Electron v27.1.2)
I look for signtool but I think is not a solution for me...
